# Calculate the Galois group of $x^6-3x^2+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I want to calculate the Galois group of the polynomial $x^6-3x^2+1$over $\Bbb{Q}$

If I let $x^2=t$, then I can calculate the Galois group of $t^3-3t+1$ is $A_3$, but is there any connection between the Galois group of $t^3-3t+1$ and $x^6-3x^2+1$?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Should be $t=x^2$, no?

Comment: Hint: Consider the extension $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(t) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(x)$, and notice $x$ satisfies the polynomial $X^2 = t$ in $\mathbb{Q}(t)[X]$. Do you know of a theorem that lets you compute the galois group of a tower of fields if you know the galois group of each step of the chain?

Comment: @OscarLanzi  oh that’s a mistake, i will fix it later

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I’m afraid i’m not familiar with this theorem, i will look for the theorem you mentioned, very thanks

Comment: The roots of the polynomial can be obtained easily with help of the cubic polynomial in $t$. It requires some effort however to show that the splitting field is of degree 24 over rationals. Have you tried calculating the splitting field explicitly?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: here $\mathbb {Q} (t) $ is the splitting field for the cubic in $t$ but $\mathbb {Q} (x) $ is not the splitting field of given polynomial.

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{Q}(t,x)$

Answer (score 2):

The discriminant of $g(t) = t^3 - 3t + 1$ is $81$, which is a square; thus the Galois group $H$ of $g$ is cyclic of order $3$. In fact, by the theorem of Kronecker Weber, the splitting field $K$ of $g$ is the totally real subfield of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_9)$, but this is irrelevant for what follows.

Let $\alpha_j$ denote the roots of $f$ and let $N$ denote the normal closure of $K(\sqrt{\alpha_1})$, i.e., the splitting field of $f$. The group $H$ permutes these quadratic extensions $K(\sqrt{\alpha_j})$, and this already shows that the Galois group of $N$ is the semidirect product of the elementary abelian group Gal$(N/K) = C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ by $H$, in other words: the wreath product of $C_2$ by $C_3$, a group of order $24$ different from $A_4$. It is instructive to fill in the details and show that the maximal abelian subextension of $N$ is $K(i)$.